# Regex for Adding Forward Slash on Character Casing

Tags: c#, regex

Admittedly regular expressions are my kryptonite, I don't even know where to begin with this one.

I need to take a string like FolderSubfolder1Subfolder2 and turn it into Folder/Subfolder1/Subfolder2 (a prefixed forward slash is ok if necessary). Basically I need to add forward slashes whenever there is an upper case letter, prior to the occurrence.

A C# use example would be appreciated, but is not required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This inserts a slash before an uppercase letter if the previous character is a lowercase letter or a digit:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=[\p{Ll}\d])(?=\p{Lu})");
newStr = regex.Replace(str, "/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(myString, "(?<!^)([A-Z])", "/$1");
```

Which will insert a forward slash before any upper case letter, provided it isn't at the beginning of your string.

Edit: by way of explanation, the `(?<!^)` is a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) - i.e don't match this if it's preceded by the start of the string `^`

The `[A-Z]` within the brackets is a capture region, whatever is succesfully matched, is then inserted where `$1` lives in the replacement string.

Note: This will fall over if you have a path name with numbers / other characters that you wish to separate with slashes, you'd have to adapt as required.

Answer (score 1):

With regex, you can do this

```
string input = "FolderSubfolder1Subfolder2 ";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"([A-Z])", "/$1").TrimStart('/');
```

Without regex, you can use this method (quick test showed that this method was almost 3 times faster than the regex and twice as fast than the regex when it's been compiled)

```
public string AddSlash(string input)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for(int i = 0;i < input.Length; i++)
     {
         if (Char.IsUpper(input[i]) && i > 0)
            sb.Append('/');

         sb.Append(input[i]);
     }

     return sb.ToString();
}
```